# Urban airship delete scheduled messagge

Tags: php, push-notification, schedule, urbanairship.com

I'm working on push notification via Urban Airship. I'm sending push notification via curl in php. I need to schedule the push notification, but in some case I have to delete a scheduled push. I scheduled the push notification, but I don't know how to delete a specific scheduled. Is it possible? Someone have any example?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out their documentation on the matter?

http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua.html#delete-schedule

Simply send a DELETE call to the schedule's ID. EG: DELETE /api/schedules/(id)

cURL example:

```
curl -v -X DELETE -u "<appkey>:<mastersecret>" https://go.urbanairship.com/api/schedules/(id)
```